# microk8s untrusted dashboard - how to verifiy certificate

Tags: macos, microk8s

I am trying out microk8s following [this](https://itnext.io/microk8s-on-macos-98f1de3aa63e)

I am getting a certificate error when browsing the dashboard(multipass ls - ip address)

I guess I need to copy and verify kuberneters certificate from multipass host(macos) on macos keychain?